# Powershell Script to click on an onclick img alt HTML element on website

Tags: java, html, css, powershell

I am trying to get my powershell script to click on the following object on a website.

***Source Code:***

```
<a onclick="document.selectAccountsGroupsForm.action='manageAccountsGroups.do?method=showAllAccounts';document.selectAccountsGroupsForm.submit();">
   <img alt="showAllAccounts" src="/TNE/images/common/buttons/btn_showAllAccounts.gif">
</a>
<input name="accountSelectionCBChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
```

**Powershell Code**

```
$ie = new-object -Com InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($url);
while($ie.busy) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;}

$ie.Document.getElementById(“userName”).value = $Username 
$ie.Document.getElementByID(“password”).value = $Password 
$ie.Document.getElementById(“loginBtn”).Click()
$link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.href -eq "document.selectAccountsGroupsForm.action='manageAccountsGroups.do?method=showAllAccountGroups';document.selectAccountsGroupsForm.submit();"}
$link.click()
```

Note: Username, Password, and URL Variables are not posted

**Error**

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
At H:\Desktop\Scripts\TEST.ps1:56 char:1 
+ $link.click() 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull –
```

Comment: What problems are you having with the code you posted? Is IE the only browser you can use?

Comment: Yeah, I can only use IE as I am using this script for work. The problem I'm having is that I need the script to click on a button called "Show All Accounts" which when clicked on does as it says

Comment: How is the code you posted not working?

Comment: When I run the code on Windows Powershell, I get the following Error:

    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    At H:\Desktop\Scripts\TEST.ps1:56 char:1
    + $link.click()
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: you should post details like the exception in the original post, rather than a couple of days later in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have done that first. I will do so going forward!

Answer (score 0):

As explain in the error your problem comes from the fact that the following line doesn't return any value:

```
$link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.href -eq "document.selectAccountsGroupsForm.action='manageAccountsGroups.do?method=showAllAccountGroups';document.selectAccountsGroupsForm.submit();"}
```

---

Edited

You perhaps can test :

```
$link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.outerhtml -like "*document.selectAccountsGroupsForm.action*"}
```

Comment: How would I edit the code to make it return a value?

Comment: I tested the code above and PowerShell returned the same error listed in the description above

Answer (score 0):

When I was developing Powershell code to control IE, I did a couple of things to debug the script. You could do one or both. I suggest trying the first one first:

1. Use the Powershell debugger. Try setting a breakpoint (`Set-BreakPoint`) on the first line that references `$ie.Document`. Then step through (`?` for help and `v` to step) line by line and check the result value of each line of your script. For example after you assign to `$ie.Document.getElementById(“userName”).value` type that expression in the debugger and see if it yields the username you expect. When you get to the line with `getElementsByTagName` you'll probably want to execute something like `$test = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')` in the debugger and then see what is in `$test`. After you understand exactly what is in `$test` you can tweak you `where-object` statement to get what you want. Or if the element isn't even in `$test` you'll know that.
2. Write little debugging functions, for things like examining the results of `getElementsByTagName`. In the debugger you can execute those debug functions as a shorthand (vs typing longer expressions in by hand). This probably doesn't make sense unless you'll be doing a lot of development/debugging with PS and IE.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter elements by "href" but your source doesn't have it.